# Laravel: Associations of multiple table using pivot

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, pivot-table, multiple-tables

Here are my tables

**boards**

```
id
board_name
```

**classes**

```
id
class_name
```

**subjects**

```
id
subject_name
```

**board_classes**

```
id
board_id
class_id
```

**board_class_subjects**

```
id
board_id
class_id
subject_id
```

I written following association in my models

**Board.php**

```
public function classes()
{
 return $this->belongsToMany('Clas','board_classes','board_id','class_id');
}
```

**Clas.php**

```
public function subjects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Subject','board_class_subjects','class_id', 'subject_id');
}
```

Not sure where would i provide condition of **class_id** while pulling records from above association. I tried:

```
$response = Board::with('classes.subjects')->where('id', 1)->get();
```

All i am getting subjects of all classes of board id 1, but i want to get all subjects of class id 1 and board id 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `whereHas` to filter the result by a related model:

```
$response = Board::with('classes.subjects')
                 ->where('id', 1)
                 ->whereHas('classes', function($q){
                     $q->where('id', 1);
                 })
                 ->get();
```

This will filter out boards that don't have a class with id 1 but still eager load all classes of the remaining boards. To change that, add the same filter to `with`:

```
$response = Board::with(['classes' => function($q){
                     $q->where('id', 1);
                 }, 'classes.subjects'])
                 ->whereHas('classes', function($q){
                     $q->where('id', 1);
                 })
                 ->find(1);
```

Comment: It is still pulling other class ids like 2,3 etc.

Comment: How would i check whether subjects not found for particular board id and class id ? i am checking this by using if ( ! $response->classes()->subjects()) {  } but it is not working

Comment: That's a bit more complicated. Since you only have one class (`id = 1`) this should work: `if($response->classes->first()->subjects->isEmpty()){ }`

Comment: After using your above code i am getting error Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$classes

Comment: My bad. Use `first()` instead of `get()` the main query. (Or remove the `where('id', 1)` and use `find(1)` at the end. See edit)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71076/discussion-between-neeraj-and-lukasgeiter).